# Simple subdomain redirect PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

I have a sub-domain for my mobile app which is like http://m.traffic.domain.com
now I want that my users can access their page by visiting http://m.traffic.domain.com/username
which will internally point to http://m.traffic.domain.com/index.php?username=$1
for this I have following .htaccess rewrite code but its not working as expected rather its redirecting all pages to http://m.traffic.domain.com/index.php?username=$1 this 
page

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .aspx
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.traffic\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^www$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ mobile/index.php?username=%1 [L]
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

The subdomain http://m.traffic.domain.com points to a directory called mobile which can be accessed http://traffic.domain.com/mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .aspx

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.traffic\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ /index.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

Matched groups from `RewriteRule` are `$1, $2` instead of `%1, %2` and you don't need `/mobile` since your request is for `m.traffic.domain.com` not `traffic.domain.com`

Comment: thanks it worked with a little edit 
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ /index.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]