# Virtual subdomains using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am trying to create virtual subdomains using .htaccess and wordpress.
But it won't seem to work properly. Using wordpress I get urls like:
    foo.eu/test-pagina/?lang=fr

I managed to rewrite this to what i want:
    fr.foo.eu/test-pagina/

But when this url is rewritten the page returns an 500 internal server error.

I also made a wildcard for the subdomains in my dns configuration.

Do I have to make subfolders for each subdomain in my root ?

My current .htaccess code is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([a-z]{2})\.hypnose\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?]*)\?lang=([a-z]{2})&?([^\ ]*)
#RewriteRule ^ http://%2.hypnose.eu/%1?%3 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]{2})\.hypnose\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?lang=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone tell me what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added "fr" as your subdomain in the domain's control panel?

Add this in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/test-pagina/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Yes i have added fr.foo.eu as subdomain

Comment: What happens if you just goto fr.foo.eu ?

Comment: Then it also displays: 500 internal server error. But the strange thing when i ping fr.foo.eu that it just replys with correct packages.

Comment: Sorry i am not that good with htaccess, i have made an edit, you can try that but i am not sure if it will work. Here is a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348615/simple-subdomain-redirect-php